# How can I convert latin1 data to UTF8 on mysql insert or update?

Tags: php, mysql, unicode, encoding

I am getting data nightly from a web service that stores their fields in latin, but my database is in utf8.
Is it possible to convert the data string to utf8 when I update or insert the record?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$output = utf8_encode ( $inputstring );
```

Read more about [utf8_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the features provided by the Multibyte String Functions in PHP. Specifically, I think that the [`mb_convert_encoding`](http://gr.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) is the function you are looking for.

```
$output = mb_convert_encoding ($input, 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1');
```

ISO-8859-1 is the official encoding standard for "Latin-1", as per [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1).